# Adyen Encryption of Credit Card Details using Python

Tags: python, curl, encryption, checkout, adyen

The Adyen packages are scattered and are not answering my questions directly. I am using python on the server side to pass credit card credentials to a website.

```
CardNumber = 4111111111111111
ExMonth = 11
ExYear = 23
CVC = 123
```

Adyen encrypts these details before it is submitted to the website:

```
"encryptedCardNumber":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...", 
"encryptedExpiryMonth":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...", 
"encryptedExpiryYear":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...", 
"encryptedSecurityCode":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
```

Do I have to perform a cURL request? Because Adyen is only giving me details as if the website belongs to me when it doesn't. This is simply to submit the information in python in a session with a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

This encryption is performed uniquely for each payment and is performed client side (on purpose) to protect card details.

This encryption has to happen on said website's page and can't be done by your backend.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you explain more about why this is the case? In our own client side applications, we try to pass around only a "card id", that is itself encrypted in the HTML form fields, but gets decrypted in our backend before making calls to backend services, one of which has authority to actually fetch a credit card number and decrypt it in memory. We would prefer to never have to render a card number into the HTML layer just to have a client-side library encrypt it.

Comment: You can handle raw card details of course, just have to be PCI compliant and Adyen has additional requirement of being a PCI Level 1/2 company (this is based on number of transaction). But if not PCI compliant, then the handling of raw card details needs to happen out of scope of the company/website, thus is done in an iframe, on the client, with unique encryption details for that specific payment. The iframe then messages back these encrypted blobs to the website scope.

Comment: luke_b, thank you for the response. I appreciate it.

Comment: luke_b, I hit enter too soon. I wanted to see if you can answer another question for me:

I've been using the TEST site to simulate an Authentication-Only flow.  I can do it fine, and I get the RedirectShopper code, the URL to POST the MD, the PaReq too. What I want to understand is this:

In the LIVE environment, will that "action" URL be a page hosted by Adyen which then renders the IFRAME which points to a URL hosted by the Issuer ACS? Or, will the "action" URL be itself hosted by the Issuer ACS? I'm trying to document how this will all work and want to have a clear picture. Thanks.

Comment: Not trying to sound dismissive but what difference does it make? Otherwise, it can be either depending on the flow. For plain 3DS1, it currently is directly to the issuer page but Adyen doesn't guarantee this as they may put an intermediary page at some point in the future. For 3ds2, if there is a 3ds1 fallback, it is an adyen URL. But ultimately it shouldn't make a difference as any adyen page is transient and doesn't affect user experience.